# Sabe REST API of Passenger Name Record NOT OPEN

Tags: rest, sabre

The below the page did not open, please let me know the REST API of "create passenger name record". I tried to open the page several days, it always failed.

I know SOAP API of "create passenger name record", What I want is REST API.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/

> Uh oh. You don’t have access to see this page. Try logging in to see if that does the trick. If that doesn't work and you think you should have access to this page, send us a note. NOTE: if you are a current customer who just registered, it can take us up to 24 hours to set up your account to see the resources. If this is an urgent request please contact us through the site.
>   Please Sign In or Register.

[Error Page as signed in - Image Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsRQc.png)

Comment: please reformulate your question to make it clearer...

Comment: When I click "https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/", nothing appears. 
I want to know how to use the REST API.

Comment: We'll probably need to see more detail than that. What URL are you using presently for the REST API? What code do you have? What do the docs say?

Comment: https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/air/book/create_passenger_name_record/  What I want is "REST API - create passenger name record".

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using?
I tryed it in different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc..) and in all of them I get a notice to sign in or register to access this page.

Comment: I used firefox, chrome, internet explorer 11, the error page is opened.
After I signed in, the error page always happened.

Comment: This is because you don't have cccess to this service. Not all services are available (neither the documentation) in the basic Access. You should ask for it to your Account Manager. Probably you must sign an agreement and pay for that service

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you're not signed in. Have you tried creating and or signing in?

Comment: Even though I signed in, I could not see valid page.

What I could see is the error page.
------------------------------------------------------------------
Uh oh. You don’t have access to see this page. Try logging in to see if that....